# Как вызвать один build.gradle из другого

Tags: java, gradle

Есть такая структура проекта.

```
ProjectMain
    build.gradle

Project1
    release
        my.jar
    build.gradle
```

Основнову проекту `ProjectMain` необходим джарник  `Project1/release/my.jar`. В `build.gradle` для `Project1` требуемая логика написана ( по генерации джарника), необходимо, чтобы при сборке `ProjectMain` использовались депенденси из `my.jar`.

Как это реализовать? (желательно, с примерами groovy кода)

P.S. до этого использовался ant, и там с этим было просто

```
<target name="one"?
    <path id="project.classpath">
              <fileset dir="${Project1.release}">
                  <patternset includes="**/*.jar"/>
              </fileset>
    </path>
</target>

<target name="Two">
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${out}" debug="on">
              <classpath refid="project.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

Это описанно вот тут: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

Если в кратце, то таску можно указать зависимость:

```
task buildWithSubProject( type: Jar, dependsOn: Project1.tasks["build"] ) {
```

Comment: А как мой build.gradle поймет, что Project1 - это тот самый, который мне нужен? Как мне прописать путь до него?

Comment: В данном примере Project1 это подпроект ProjectMain. Gradle сам найдёт его по названию. Если нужно, чтобы Project1 не был подпроектом, то его нужно указать как внешнюю зависимость. Можно использовать [локальный maven репозиторий](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html#sub:installing_to_the_local_repository) для этого.

Comment: Project1 не является подпроектом. Они лежат рядом друг с другом